# Why is it not possible for me to write into a file?

Tags: java, log4j2

I am using log4j2 to log messages to the console and a text file. I could log things to the console but i am not able to write into the text file (text file is empty)
here are the code

```
package de.code.logwizard;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.Configurator;

public class Log4JarLogger 
{
    public static Logger getLogger(Class<?> clazz) 
    {
        return LogManager.getLogger(clazz);
    }

    public static void configure()
    {
        final String propertyFileName = System.getProperty("user.dir") + LOG4J_FILE;
        System.out.println(propertyFileName);
        Configurator.initialize(null, propertyFileName);
        LogManager.getLogger(Log4JarLogger.class).info("Logging initialized from file '" + propertyFileName + "'.");
    }

    private static final String LOG4J_FILE = "\\log4j2Test.properties";
}
```

--

```
import de.code.logwizard.Log4JarLogger;

public class TestLogger 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Log4JarLogger.configure();
        _logger = Log4JarLogger.getLogger(TestLogger.class);
        _logger.debug("This is DEBUG");
        _logger.info("This is INFO");
        _logger.warn("This is WARN");
        _logger.error("This is ERROR");
        _logger.fatal("This is FATAL");
    }

    private static org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger _logger;
}
```

and the properties file :

```
property.filename = logs
appenders = console, file

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName = target/rolling/rollingtest.log
appender.file.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

loggers = file
logger.file.name = com.testcase 
logger.file.level = debug
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT
```

I would guess that the line Configurator.initialize(null, propertyFileName); is the reason that it does not work out?

Comment: Please tell us which JAR logging dependencies you included (check your Maven POM file).

Comment: I have a dependency to log4j-api-2.12.0.jar and log4j-core-2.12.0.jar. I dont use maven in my project

Comment: I would strongly recommend using one of the [automatic configuration options](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#AutomaticConfiguration) rather than making your code depend on the log4j2 implementation.

Comment: Do the [status messages](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#StatusMessages) provide any insights? What do they tell you?

Comment: unfortunately I dont have any error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

log4j logger configuration is the problem. If you want to log in file as well as on console both, try changing your logger configuration like -

```
loggers = file
# mention your root package name of the project in below key
logger.file.name = de.code.logwizard
logger.file.level = debug
logger.file.additivity = debug
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE
logger.file.appenderRef.console.ref = STDOUT

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.additivity = false
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = LOGFILE
rootLogger.appenderRef.console.ref = STDOUT
```

Coming to the issues in your configuration file -

1. `logger.file.name` value should be the root package name of the project. However, in your configuration file, it was `com.testcase`
2. Syntax error on appender reference declaration. It should be `appenderRef` instead of `appenderRefs`

Comment: Can you also tell me where I can read how to write the log4j2 properties file?

Comment: You need not to write on the log file directly. You logger methods like `logger.debug` will write on the console as well as on file. Also, as per your configuration file, logs will be written on `target/rolling/rollingtest.log` file.

Comment: Can you please explain *what* was going wrong instead of just giving the corrected version? Teach a man how to fish... ;)

Comment: Thanks, =1 from me then :)